# Importing large CSV in local Mysql workbench is very slow

Tags: mysql

I want to import a 60mb csv file into my Mysql workbench.
The problem is that I have used the import wizard and it has been running for 2 days and only been completed about 60%.
I am using workbench on my local computer.
How can I get this done faster?

Comment: Load data infile?

Comment: I am using the table import wizard

Comment: Sorry, That was a suggestion not a request for clarification.

Comment: Can you share your method in detail? And if it is faster than the import wizard

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?  Are other queries running against the table?  Are you adding the data to a table with data already in it, or is this a fresh load?  (There are many possible explanations to "slow"; some have useful workarounds.)

Comment: The fact is when corporations like Oracle buys out open source projects they purposely make them fail and turn them into turds. Oracle is the worst. They haven't made an honest in-house product worth a damn in well over a decade. All they do is buy out or take ownership of the rights of other people's work and slap their brand on it until it becomes obsolete and then repeats the process. They are a cancer of the tech industry and our society. This bug has existed for very, very long time and is a prime example of this fact.